# Setting the background color of a Bokeh layout element

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh and I have a Bokeh script and I wish to change the background color of a column. Is this possible? Something like `lay.background="blue"`?

```py
laybuttons=widgetbox([button, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5])
lay=column(laybuttons)

show(row(lay, s2, s3))
```

Comment: I am also trying to figure out this but still struggling. Have you figured out?

Comment: No alas i have not